# Db2 XML logics framing in select statement

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

In db2,

```
<row><element name>January</element name>
<error code>1010<\error code></row>
```

Need to frame as like this in db2 select statement.

In SQL server will handle this with the help of XML path()

Comment: What do you mean by “Need to frame”?

Comment: In select statement need this output.

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want to produce XML from two (standard) relational columns, or do you want to produce two columns from an XML value?

Comment: In table, element name and error code as column name , January and 1010 as data's.Need output as above mentioned in a XML in a select statement.

Comment: Have you tried the example below as is?

Comment: What column and table name is your XML value stored in?  Mark's example should be enough for you to show you what you need. If not, you need to explain better the issue that you are struggling with. What SQL have you tried so far, what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM 
(
VALUES
'
<row>
  <element_name>January</element_name>
  <error_code>1010</error_code>
</row>
'
,
'
<row>
  <element_name>February</element_name>
  <error_code>2020</error_code>
</row>
'
) D(X)
, XMLTABLE
(
'$X/row' PASSING XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT D.X) AS "X"
COLUMNS
  ENAME VARCHAR(10) PATH 'element_name'
, ERROR INT         PATH 'error_code'
) T
```

which produces this output

```
ENAME    ERROR
-------- -----
January   1010
February  2020
```